# How to calculate the minimum of the difference between the upper and lower bounds of an interval?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, z-score

Let's say $X$ ~ N(500, $50^2$) and $P(a<X<b)=0.95$. How can I calculate minimum(b-a)?

Comment: Hint: first demonstrate that $b-500 = 500-a.$  Drawing a graph of the density might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the difference to be minimum, it needs to be symmetric around the mean, as also pointed out in the comments. Then, you normalize the RV $X$: $$P(a<X<b)=P\left(\frac{a-500}{50}<Z<\frac{b-500}{50}\right)=0.95$$

The upper tail has 0.025 probability. Using a standard normal table ([Z-table](http://www.z-table.com/)) we can find the upper (or lower depending on the table) end as $1.96$. The lower end will be negative of this, leading to $a,b$.

Comment: So, a = 402 and b = 598. Thank you both

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that we *have* an interval $(a,b)$ such that $P(a < X < b)=0.95$ and suppose we move the left endpoint rightwards by a *small amount* $\delta$ so that the left endpoint is at $a+\delta$. Clearly, $P(a+\delta < X < b)$ is smaller than $0.95$ and so we should move the right endpoint a tad to the right too, to $b+\varepsilon$, say, so that $P(a+\delta < X < b+\varepsilon)$ equals $0.95$. But what is $\varepsilon$ and how does it compare to $\delta$?  Well, and looking at a graph of the normal density $f(x)$ is very helpful here, the move of the left endpoint from $a$ to $a+\delta$ cut off an area $\approx f(a)\cdot \delta$ and so the move of the right endpoint must add back that much area, that is,
$$f(a)\cdot \delta = f(b)\cdot \varepsilon.$$

- If $f(a) < f(b)$, then $\delta > \varepsilon$ and the new interval $(a+\delta, b+\varepsilon)$ has length $$b+\varepsilon -(a+\delta) = b-a -(\delta-\varepsilon) < b-a.$$
- If $f(a) > f(b)$, then $\delta < \varepsilon$ and the new interval $(a+\delta, b+\varepsilon)$ has length $$b+\varepsilon -(a+\delta) = b-a +(\varepsilon-\delta) > b-a.$$

So, the shortest interval $(a,b)$ is the one where $a$ and $b$ are chosen such that $f(a) = f(b)$ and, once again looking at the graph of the density function, we wee that $a$ and $b$ must be equally distant from the mean.

Comment: Great probabilistic demonstration Dilip. So, you agree with the solution that a=402 and b=598?